# Format date to concatenate with text

Tags: excel-2016

I need to format a invoice number that needs to be in a specific format (yyyymm(Textvalue)

=YEAR(D5) &""& MONTH(D5) & "MarCall"  = currently returns:  20165MarCall

Need to check for two digit month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
=IF(MONTH(D5)<10, "0" & MONTH(D5), MONTH(D5))
```